# Altera Clock + PLL

Tags: clock, intel-fpga, pll

I am using an Altera devkit from terasic, DE0-CV. I am also new to the FPGA business.

How to connect the onboard clock to the FPGA and use it with my design?

As the clock is a 50 MHz one, surely I will need to drop it down to 1 to 10 Hz only. I heard about PLL inside the FPGA device but I am not able to figure it out how to setup and use.

the board comes with a cyclone V device.

Answer (score 2):

The clock would be connected on the board to a pin you can use as a clock input.

To understand what you are doing, I'd start with a simple project and then improve that.

The first implementation would not be using the PLL at all, rather you just want to have some blinking thingy to see that it works.

1. Make a simple toplevel `entity` with a `std_logic` input and a `std_logic` output port.
2. Find out which pin the clock is connected to, and a pin that is connected to an LED, and map the ports from the toplevel to the pins.
3. create an `architecture` for that toplevel component that divides the clock input frequency to something visible. A primitive implementation would have a counter that counts down from `50000000` to `0` on each `rising_edge` of the clock, and when it arrives at `0`, resets to the start value, and toggles the LED output.
4. compile and run, see whether you get a one second blink.

Using the PLL requires you to use the "MegaWizard" to create and configure a PLL component, then add it as a subcomponent to your toplevel and connect the inputs and outputs. Generally you wouldn't be able to divide by 50M with the PLL, since its numerator/denominator ranges are smaller than that, but you could for example build a 4/5 PLL, reuse the counter from earlier and see whether you really get 40000000 ticks per second out of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DE0-CV, there is a tool from terrasic that generates a skeleton application. You can open this skeleton application in quartus. 
Once you have this, you can add the following code to the .v verilog file within quartus. Compile and download the program to your board and a digital clock should be visible on the screen. To go from 50MHz to 1Hz you can use a counter or a series of counters. PLL's are much more complex than counters. The example code below generates a number of low frequency clocks based on the 50Mhz system clock.

```
//=======================================================
//  This code is generated by Terasic System Builder
//=======================================================

module Project5(

    //////////// CLOCK //////////
    input                       CLOCK_50,
    input                       CLOCK2_50,
    input                       CLOCK3_50,
    inout                       CLOCK4_50,

    //////////// SEG7 //////////
    output           [6:0]      HEX0,
    output           [6:0]      HEX1,
    output           [6:0]      HEX2,
    output           [6:0]      HEX3,
    output           [6:0]      HEX4,
    output           [6:0]      HEX5,

    //////////// KEY //////////
    input            [3:0]      KEY,
    input                       RESET_N,

    //////////// LED //////////
    output           [9:0]      LEDR,

    //////////// microSD Card //////////
    output                      SD_CLK,
    inout                       SD_CMD,
    inout            [3:0]      SD_DATA,

    //////////// SW //////////
    input            [9:0]      SW
);



//=======================================================
//  Main
//=======================================================

wire w1Sec,w1Min,w1Hour,w100mSec;
wire[7:0 ] sec, min, hr;
wire incSec;
wire incMin;
wire incHr;

// invert keys (input 1 == not pressed, pull up resistor)
assign incSec=~KEY[0];
assign incMin=~KEY[1];
assign incHr=~KEY[2];

// make 100ms 500ms and 1 second pulses (square wave)
PULSE puls100msec(CLOCK_50,5000000,w100mSec);
PULSE puls500msec(CLOCK_50,25000000,w500mSec);
PULSE pulssec(CLOCK_50, 50000000,w1Sec);

// count pulses + cascade counters
CTR clocksec(w1Sec,w500mSec,w100mSec,incSec,~RESET_N,59,sec,w1Min);
CTR clockmin(w1Min,w500mSec,w100mSec,incMin,~RESET_N,59,min,w1Hour);
CTR clockhr(w1Hour,w500mSec,w100mSec,incHr,~RESET_N,23,hr);

// show display
BYTETO7SEG digit0000XX(sec,HEX1,HEX0);
BYTETO7SEG digit00xx00(min,HEX3,HEX2);
BYTETO7SEG digitxx0000(hr,HEX5,HEX4);

// control leds:
assign LEDR[0]=w100mSec;
assign LEDR[1]=w500mSec;
assign LEDR[2]=w1Sec;
assign LEDR[3]=w1Min;
assign LEDR[4]=w1Hour;

endmodule


//=======================================================
//  counter sec/min of clock:
//=======================================================

module CTR(w1,w2,w3,inc,fast,valRef,val,w);
input wire w1,w2,w3,inc,fast;
input wire [7:0] valRef;
output reg [7:0] val;
output reg w;

wire trig = (w1 & ~inc) || ((inc & w2 & ~fast) || (inc & w3 & fast));

always @(posedge trig)
begin
  if (val>=valRef)  
  begin
     val <= 0;
     if (~inc)
        w <= 1;
  end
  else
  begin
    val <= val + 1;    
    w <= 0;
  end
end
endmodule


//=======================================================
//  Pulse x hz from 50 mhz clock:
//=======================================================

module PULSE(clk,qRef,w);
input wire clk;
input wire [63:0] qRef;
output reg w;
reg [63:0] q;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  if (q>=qRef)  
  begin
     q <= 0;
     w <= 1;
  end
  else
  begin
    q <= q + 1;  
     w <= 0;
  end
end
endmodule

//=======================================================
//  hex to 7 seg control:
//=======================================================
module BYTETO7SEG(bt,seg1,seg2);

input wire [7:0] bt;
output reg [6:0] seg1;
output reg [6:0] seg2;

wire [3:0] x; 
wire [3:0] y;

assign x = bt / 10;
assign y = bt % 10;

always @(bt)
begin       
    case (x)
    4'b0000 : seg1 = 7'b1000000;        //Hexadecimal 0
    4'b0001 : seg1 = 7'b1111001;        //Hexadecimal 1
    4'b0010 : seg1 = 7'b0100100;        //Hexadecimal 2
    4'b0011 : seg1 = 7'b0110000;        //Hexadecimal 3
    4'b0100 : seg1 = 7'b0011001;        //Hexadecimal 4
    4'b0101 : seg1 = 7'b0010010;        //Hexadecimal 5
    4'b0110 : seg1 = 7'b0000010;        //Hexadecimal 6
    4'b0111 : seg1 = 7'b1111000;        //Hexadecimal 7
    4'b1000 : seg1 = 7'b0000000;        //Hexadecimal 8
    4'b1001 : seg1 = 7'b0010000;        //Hexadecimal 9
    4'b1010 : seg1 = 7'b0001000;        //Hexadecimal A
    4'b1011 : seg1 = 7'b0000011;        //Hexadecimal B
    4'b1100 : seg1 = 7'b1000110;        //Hexadecimal C
    4'b1101 : seg1 = 7'b0100001;        //Hexadecimal D
    4'b1110 : seg1 = 7'b0000110;        //Hexadecimal E
    4'b1111 : seg1 = 7'b0001110;        //Hexadecimal F // low logic = burning led
    endcase

    case (y)
    4'b0000 : seg2 = 7'b1000000;        //Hexadecimal 0
    4'b0001 : seg2 = 7'b1111001;        //Hexadecimal 1
    4'b0010 : seg2 = 7'b0100100;        //Hexadecimal 2
    4'b0011 : seg2 = 7'b0110000;        //Hexadecimal 3
    4'b0100 : seg2 = 7'b0011001;        //Hexadecimal 4
    4'b0101 : seg2 = 7'b0010010;        //Hexadecimal 5
    4'b0110 : seg2 = 7'b0000010;        //Hexadecimal 6
    4'b0111 : seg2 = 7'b1111000;        //Hexadecimal 7
    4'b1000 : seg2 = 7'b0000000;        //Hexadecimal 8
    4'b1001 : seg2 = 7'b0010000;        //Hexadecimal 9
    4'b1010 : seg2 = 7'b0001000;        //Hexadecimal A
    4'b1011 : seg2 = 7'b0000011;        //Hexadecimal B
    4'b1100 : seg2 = 7'b1000110;        //Hexadecimal C
    4'b1101 : seg2 = 7'b0100001;        //Hexadecimal D
    4'b1110 : seg2 = 7'b0000110;        //Hexadecimal E
    4'b1111 : seg2 = 7'b0001110;        //Hexadecimal F // low logic = burning led
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

Comment: This design could be improved by making the w1Sec, w1Min and w1hour counters BCD rather than binary.  This would avoid the need to divide bt / 10 and bt % 10 in BYTETOSEG and allow a far more sensible seven segment module definition that takes one 4-bit value + an enable and drives one display, not 2.